# React Router Dom - Set route name for dynamic route and access it in sibling component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router-dom` for my react project and I have this basic routes structure

```js
        <Router>
          <div className="app-container">
            <Navbar />
            <Suspense fallback={<ReactLazyLoadingScreen />}>
              <Switch>
                {getRoutes(isAuthenticated, privateRoutes)}
                <Route exact path="/:courseSlug" component={CourseDetailsContainer} />
                <Redirect to="/404" />
              </Switch>
            </Suspense>
          </div>
        </Router>
```

Here when the route with dynamic path `/:courseSlug` is rendered, I want to know that in `Navbar` Component.

In `Navbar` component I have exported with `WithRouter` HOC like below

```
export default withRouter(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavbarComponent)
)
```

When I try to access `location` or `history` there is no property which I can use to say that `CourseDetailsContainer` is rendered.

```
    const { history, location } = this.props;
    console.log({ props: this.props });
    console.log({ history, location });
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to utilize `props.computedMatch`:

```
let courseSlug = props?.computedMatch?.params?.courseSlug
```

I'm not 100% sure you could actually access that via the `<Navbar>` component though, so you may have to check for it inside the `<Route>` component and then pass the boolean back out to your `<Router>`, or use a redux configuration to communicate the data across the components.